# Spring WebServiceTemplate URL

Tags: spring-ws

In the [Spring guides a webservice is published](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) at locationUri "/ws".
The  getCountryRequest [webservice is consumed](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) using the WebServiceTemplate's marshallSendAndReceive method at "http://localhost:8080/ws/countries".

When using soapUI I consume the webservice at "http://localhost:8080/ws/" and specify the name of the webservice in the SOAP body.

So how does the WebServiceTemplate exactly use the "countries" suffix and how does it exactly map to the message with name getCountryRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
The wsdl is publishing the webservice at

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws"/>
```

But the MessageDispatcherServlet is listening at "http://localhost:8080/ws/*".
So anything beneath that URL is just passed onto SOAP and works.

I can use http://localhost:8080/ws/ (I still wonder why the WebServiceTemplate doesn't just use the WSDL SOAP address), http://localhost:8080/ws/countries or http://localhost:8080/ws/anythingGoes. 
It just doesn't matter.